# Instagram to filter by location, hashtag and keyword

Tags: instagram

Is there any alternative webservices for instagram that allows one to search our own photo by location, hash tag and keyword?

If not, does the Instagram API allows developer to develop such function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instagram API does not have API to do hashtag + location or multiple hashtags.

APIs can be combined and search can be done to get photos from a location and then filter for keyword or hashtag, but this will be inefficient since each location API will return 20 photos at a time. Depending on hashtag there may be too many photos at the location, you will have to get 20 at a time and then perform filter by keyword.

This approach has been implemented in `gramfeed` search: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/search
You can search by location and filter by keyword.
You can also search by hashtag and then filter by keyword.

Comment: Hi @krisrak, gramfeed looks cool and the keyword search is good. However, the date function can only set "before date" but not "between date". Also, I can't seems to search my own photos based on location keyword. Nevertheless, the photo map is good enough. 

Overall, I think this is a good web based version for instagram as compared to the official site.

Thanks.

Comment: instagram only sorts photos from latest date, did not implement end date cause u can stop scrolling and stop at a date, can be done, just UI has to be thought about. For your own photos, you can open the map and look for location, can be done also, but not many have requested.

Comment: Somehow gramfeed has been bought over and it is no longer free. Any free alternative to recommend?

Comment: You do all the things you could do with gramfeed on picodash, but its not free, there is 3 day free trial.

Answer (score 0):

**Instagram API does not allow to look for media by multiple filters all at once.** However, it is possible to fetch pictures by specified hashtag and then manually filter each one by given location and other criteria.